# value error in python cv

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

I am trying to change black pattern in a monochrome 3 channel QR to any another color but I am getting this error all the time

> if k.any()==[0,0,0]:
>   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

code I am trying is given below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('C:/New folder (2)/new1.png')

rows,cols,bands = img.shape 
print rows,cols,bands
for i in xrange (rows):
    for j in xrange (cols):
        k = img[i,j]
        if k.any()==[0,0,0]:
            img[i,j]==[255,255,255]
cv2.imshow('r',r)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The image which I am using is attached below. Please help me to get out of this.

[QR Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m38oE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have corrected your indentation errors in your post, you had two minor errors:

1.) Wrong syntax for np.any()

2.) Assigning the new pixel value, you did a comparison instead, which had no effect on the value.

Corrected code with comments is attached:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('image.png')

rows,cols,bands = img.shape 
print rows,cols,bands
for i in xrange (rows):
    for j in xrange (cols):
        k = img[i,j]
        #corrected syntax for comparison of multiple components
        if np.all(k==[0,0,0]):
            # Use = instead of == in next line, you do not want to compate
            img[i,j]=[120,0,255]
cv2.imshow('r',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However one final remark: I have only directly answered your question, looping over single pixels is not at all a solution you should choose with OpenCV.

Though this looks more complicated, a more adequate (and faster) way to do this in OpenCV would look like:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('image.png')

rows,cols,bands = img.shape 
print rows,cols,bands

# Create image with new colour for replacement
new_colour_image= np.zeros((rows,cols,3), np.uint8)
new_colour_image[:,:]= (255,0,0) 

# Define range of color to be exchanged (in this case only one single color, but could be range of colours)
lower_limit = np.array([0,0,0])
upper_limit = np.array([0,0,0])

# Generate mask for the pixels to be exchanged
new_colour_mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower_limit, upper_limit)

# Generate mask for the pixels to be kept
old_image_mask=cv2.bitwise_not(new_colour_mask)


# Part of the image which is kept
img2= cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, old_image_mask)

# Part of the image which is replaced
new_colour_image=cv2.bitwise_and(new_colour_image,new_colour_image, new_colour_mask)

#Combination of the two parts
result=cv2.bitwise_or(img2, new_colour_image)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.imshow('mask',new_colour_mask)
cv2.imshow('r',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: thanx a ton.. may be while pasting program in post, indentation error is introduced. Using mask for this is really a very good solution since, with this program becomes faster..you made my day

Answer (score 0):

Here you wanna compare your array with [0,0,0], however, k.any() will return a boolean but not an array, so cannot be compared with [0,0,0]

There are some ways to fix this. I would like to suggest to use

if k.any() or k.all() directly. both of them return a boolean value, and any() check if there is none-0, all() check if there is a 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering...I thought k.any() will check if there is any 0 value in the array. Now fixed this. Thanks for the help